# How can I show only last year posts in wordpress archive?

Tags: wp-query, widgets

I am using Wordpress archive widget to display archives of My WordPress site. But there is a condition, I want to display only last year archives, not this year. I am using inbuilt widget, so what can I do to stop this year's archive coming on the widget?

Comment: So you want to use the default Archive widget but restrict it only to the last year or do you want to remove only the current year?

Answer (score 0):

test below plugin . I hope your problem is resolved

[Simple Yearly Archive](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/)

[Archives by Category and Date](https://wordpress.org/plugins/archives-by-category-and-date/)

Answer (score 0):

Use below function in your function file.

```
    function limit_archives( $args ) {
    $args['limit'] = 1;
    $args['type'] = yearly;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_archives_args', 'limit_archives' );
add_filter( 'widget_archives_dropdown_args', 'limit_archives' );
```